# Is there a way to display fragments in TabHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'd like to show a different fragment in a TabHost, for every tab. But 
it seems that there's no easy way to do this. TabHost can only accept 
A. Views or B. Intents that launch Activities when the user selects a 
tab.

Going with A means that I have to initialize every fragment and load 
them into container Views that are given to the TabHost. But I want 
these fragments to load only when needed - when the user selects their 
tab that is.

Going with B means that I load the fragments into separate Activities 
for each tab. But I'd like the fragment to be able to reach the 
"original" parent Activity, not just some shell Activity that hosts 
them in a tab content.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to manage fragments with 
TabHost properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some hits here:

1. [fragment Support with Tabhost](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ea3b64b8b4ac8ab1)
2. [Android 1.6 & Fragment & Tabhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556746/android-1-6-fragment-tabhost)

For what I understood, "link" a fragment inside a TabHost isn't allowed, you need to create activities that include your fragments and then call these activities from TabHost.

**EDIT**
the "official solution" [from Google](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html), and with [nice animations](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html).

Comment: the "official solution" should remain. please delete the other links

Comment: The official solution redirects to samples page, which says to download the samples. In the ApiDemos FragmentTabs only uses ActionBar tabs, ordinary tabs are done using deprecated TabActivity. I would appreciate if someone clarified which is the preferred way, use deprecated or not?

Comment: This link is quite useful: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/