# Fragments vs. Activities for Tab Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-activity

I am trying to implement a tabbed navigation in my android app, however I want to run a different activity in each tab. I've been reading the android development page and they insist on using fragments for navigation over activities. From what I understand, you cannot have a fragment class by itself, it must be contained in an activity.

Is it possible to create a new activity for each tab and run that activity in the onTabSelected() function, while displaying the UI for each tab from the fragment within the running activity?

TabHost has been deprecated for Fragments, but I have been unable to find a way to navigate through activities by tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you don't want to have separated Activities for each tab (although I've seen such apps :() . Basically - Activity is a top-container, and any TabHost View is a child of such Activity. Switch to the Fragments, check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891923/1434631
this: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/
and this: http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/

Comment: So basically I will have one activity that host all the fragments, and each fragment will act like an activity? To me this seems to be bad formatting since all the fragments will be subclasses to one fragmentactivity class.